# Acumatica - Fields do not load when item selected from PXSelector

Tags: customization, selector, acumatica

I'm having trouble getting my fields to load when a value is selected from a selector.  First screen (Group-Categories) has a Group Selector that displays description in textfield and grid where users can input Categories and Cat Descriptions.  This works perfectly.

```
// Group DAC 
[Serializable]
public class INMerchandiseGroup : IBqlTable
{
    #region GroupCD
    [PXDBString(10, IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(INMerchandiseGroup.groupCD))]    
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Group Code", Visibility=PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<INMerchandiseGroup.groupCD>),
    typeof(INMerchandiseGroup.groupCD),
    typeof(INMerchandiseGroup.description))]
    public virtual string GroupCD { get; set; }
    public abstract class groupCD : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<groupCD> { }
    #endregion

    #region Description
    [PXDBString(256, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(INMerchandiseGroup.description))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public abstract class description : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<description> { }
    #endregion
}

// Group Graph
public class BPGroupCategoryMaint : PXGraph<BPGroupCategoryMaint, INMerchandiseGroup>
{    
    // Setup for GroupCd in grid 
    #region Category GroupCD
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(INMerchandiseGroup.groupCD))]
    protected virtual void INMerchandiseCategory_GroupCD_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {
    }
    #endregion   

    public PXSelect<INMerchandiseGroup> CurrentGroup;
    public PXSave<INMerchandiseGroup> Save;
    public PXCancel<INMerchandiseGroup> Cancel;

    public PXSelect<INMerchandiseCategory,
    Where<INMerchandiseCategory.groupCD, Equal<Current<INMerchandiseGroup.groupCD>>>>
    GroupCategories;
}
```

I have same setup in Category-Dept screen.  User selects Category from selector and the Cat Description and Group CD should populate text boxes, but category description and groupcd only populate the first time.  After that, the values in cache are null.  What am I doing incorrectly?

```
// Category DAC (this is used in the grid of Group screen, and as a record header in Category screen.
[Serializable]
public class INMerchandiseCategory : IBqlTable
{     
    #region CategoryCD
    [PXDBString(10,  IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(INMerchandiseCategory.categoryCD, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Category Code")]
    public virtual string CategoryCD { get; set; }
    public abstract class categoryCD : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<categoryCD> { }       
    #endregion

    #region Description
    [PXDBString(256, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(INMerchandiseCategory.categoryDescription))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Category Description")]
    public virtual string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
    public abstract class categoryDescription : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<categoryDescription> { }
    #endregion

    #region GroupCD
    [PXDBString(10, IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(INMerchandiseCategory.groupCD) )]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Group Code")]
    public virtual string GroupCD { get; set; }
    public abstract class groupCD : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<groupCD> { }
    #endregion      
}

// Category Graph
public class BPCategoryDeptMaint : PXGraph<BPCategoryDeptMaint>
{
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Category Code", Visibility=PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]   
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<INMerchandiseCategory.categoryCD,
    InnerJoin<INMerchandiseGroup, On<INMerchandiseCategory.groupCD, Equal<INMerchandiseGroup.groupCD>>>>),
    typeof(INMerchandiseCategory.categoryCD),
    typeof(INMerchandiseCategory.categoryDescription),
    typeof(INMerchandiseCategory.groupCD),
    typeof(INMerchandiseGroup.description))]    
    protected virtual void INMerchandiseCategory_CategoryCD_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }

    #region Dept GroupCD
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXDefault(typeof(INMerchandiseCategory.groupCD), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    protected virtual void INMerchandiseDept_GroupCD_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {
    }
    #endregion     

    #region Dept CategoryCD
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXDefault(typeof(INMerchandiseCategory.categoryCD), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    protected virtual void INMerchandiseDept_CategoryCD_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {
    }
    #endregion     

    public PXSelect<INMerchandiseCategory> CurrentCategory;
    public PXSave<INMerchandiseCategory> Save;
    public PXCancel<INMerchandiseCategory> Cancel;

    public PXSelect<INMerchandiseDept,
    Where<INMerchandiseDept.groupCD, Equal<Current<INMerchandiseCategory.groupCD>>,
    And<INMerchandiseDept.categoryCD, Equal<Current<INMerchandiseCategory.categoryCD>>>>>
    CategoryDepts;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the field in the ASPX has attribute commit=true.  If flagged for commit, then the UI will send the update to the server when the control is changed.

Comment: The ASPX already has CommitChanges="true".  Is there another Commit?

Comment: No.  I notice that GroupCD is set as a key.  Was that intentional?